# dense lattices in high dimensions

Tags: na.numerical-analysis, integration

I want a collection of points $\{ x_1, \dots, x_m\}$ to sample a unit cube $[0,1]^n$ with $n >>1 $ in high dimensions so that summing over these points is approximate the integral over that space.

$$\frac{1}{m} \sum f(x_i) \approx \int_{[0,1]^n} f(x) \ dx $$

If I broke each segment $[0,1]$ into $10$ points, I would have to calculate $10^n$ values of my function $f$ - way too many.

Are there lattices I can use which become dense in $[0,1]^n$ as the mesh gets smaller, and whose points do not grow too quickly?

If I knew more about lattices, I could make this more precise.

Comment: Avoiding the exponential explosion here is commonly known as _stratified sampling_ and you might have some luck  searching under that term.

Answer (score 5):

This paper seems to directly address your question:

> Art Owen. "Latin supercube sampling for very high-dimensional simulations."
>   *ACM Transactions on Modeling and Computer Simulation* (TOMACS).
>   Volume 8, Issue 1, Jan. 1998.
>   ([ACM link](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=273010))

Here is its first sentence:

---

[image: Owen1stSentence]

---

The paper includes summaries of Latin hypercube sampling (LHS) and quasi-Monte Carlo (QMC)
sampling; it cites about 50 references.

Answer (score 2):

You face the **[curse of dimensionality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curse_of_dimensionality)**. Besides the pretty old but simple and robust *[Monte Carlo integration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monte_Carlo_integration)* and its relatives there are also methods based on *[sparse grids](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_grid)*. For an overview see

> E. Novak, "High dimensional integration", Advances in Computational Mathematics, volume 12, issue 1, 2000

or the slightly older

> E Novak, K Ritter, "High dimensional integration of smooth functions over cubes", Numerische Mathematik, volume 75, issue 1, 1996.